# Can you store WordPress post word counts in custom fields on post status change?

Tags: php, wordpress

Say I have the following Post Statuses within WordPress:

1. Draft (default)
2. Pending Review
3. Pending Submission

Is it possible (and if so, how) to record the Post Edit screen's WYSIWYG editor's word count and save it as a database entry / custom field (for later reference) when the Post Status changes from 1 to 2, and then from 2 to 3?

Here's a screenshot to clarify what I mean by the word count: [WordPress Post Edit screen word count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZJOM.png).

Answer (score 0):

Just before to change your post state, get your post data and take your content and try with this function to get the count words:

```
<?php str_word_count ( string $string [, int $format = 0 [, string $charlist ]] ) ?>
```

After this, record your custom field with this:

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique); ?>
```

I think the image you show it count words with JavaScript, not with PHP.